# Chart of mutable versus immutable types

Tags: python, types, immutability, mutable

Is there a table or a chart somewhere online which shows what types (inbuilt) are mutable and immutable in python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure of a chart, but basically:

**Mutable:**

`list`, `dictionary`, `bytearray` 
Note: `bytearray` is not a sequence though.

**Immutable:**

`tuple`, `str`

You can check for mutability with:

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = range(10)
>>> s = "Hello World"
>>> isinstance(l, collections.MutableSequence)
True
>>> isinstance(s, collections.MutableSequence)
False
```

For a dictionary (mapping):

```
>>> isinstance({}, collections.MutableMapping)
True
```

Comment: This checks whether it's a mutable sequence--not whether it's a mutable object.  Dicts are clearly mutable objects, but `isinstance({}, collections.MutableSequence)` is false.

Comment: Yes, for dicts, `MutableMapping` is used. I didn't mention because I took the example of list. I will update it.

Comment: That doesn't work for sets.  My point is just that `collections` won't tell you in a generic way whether an object is mutable or immutable.

Comment: Ok. Then what is the generic way to check for it? Feel free to update the answer.

Comment: @Sukbir: Add `bytearray` to the mutable chart (py3 only). Also there's `array.array` which may not be "built-in" in a narrow sense but is usually present.

Comment: @Sukbir: It turns out that `array.array` doesn't even qualify as a `collections. Sequence` (it doesn't have `__reversed__`) let alone as a `MutableSequence`. It is very definitely a mutable sequence for practical purposes.

Comment: @John: Good point, but the mutability does hold true for it. If you feel the need, please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, `bytearray` was backported to 2.6 also.

Comment: In python all built-in immutable types are hashable. All built-in mutable types are not hashable. It's a bit obscure, but you can check immutability of any built-in (not only collections) by checking if it's hashable...

Comment: aren't Int and float also immutable?

Comment: Are functions mutable?